# Authentication with cookies in react

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a login authentication function using React and will employ cookies as the authentication method.
Which is the best way to do this, to receive the token on the front side, store it in a cookie, or pass it to the backend (node.js), and which is more common, to send the cookie from the front side or to send and check the cookie from the request on the backend side? What is more common?

Comment: it sounds like you need to do more research on the matter. Also you should put what code you have attempted first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.